# Asus Zenfone Max Z010D - Bootloop problem

Tags: boot-loop

My Asus Zenfone Max Z010D on Android 6.0.1 suddenly started showing, "Unfortunately, Google Play Music has stopped" and it did the same for almost every app, and restarted on its own.

After some research, I came to know that it went into a boot loop because it is continuously loading and does not start after that.

With zero knowledge of Android and two days of Google search, I tried the following things, however, nothing has solved the problem and my phone is still not working.

I tried:

1. ADB sideloading: I switched the phone to recovery mode, and selected apply update from ADB. I found the firmware file for my model from the official Asus site and executed the following command from my PC: `adb sideload UL-ASUS_Z010-WW-13.8.26.110-user.zip`

   However, it showed the following error:

   ```
   E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
   E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
   E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
   E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
   E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
   E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
   ```

   <sup>[Original screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyEJ6l.jpg)</sup>

   I was not able to find a solution to the error.
2. Secondly, I tried flashing the boot image available in the extracted firmware file as follows:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb devices
   List of devices attached
   GBAXB700D719RCK recovery

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb reboot bootloader

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot devices
   GBAXB700D719RCK fastboot

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot boot.img
   target reported max download size of 26843546 bytes
   sending 'boot' (9740 KB)...
   OKAY [  0.339s]
   writing 'boot'...
   OKAY [  0.212s]
   finished. total time: 0.552s

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot reboot
   rebooting...

   finished. total time: 0.003s

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>
   ```

   <sup>[Original screenshot of the terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg6XA.png)</sup>

   Even after that, it kept on loading with the logo on the screen and never started properly.

Maybe everything that I have said and done is wrong. Please help me to get my phone working properly.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. The `boot` image is just a very small run-time which is executed at the beginning of the boot process. If it is finished it loads the `system` or the `recovery`. I assume that the installed bootloader works without problems, but your installed OS (containing the kernel and the system partition) is still broken. I would recommend to flash TWRP recovery via fastboot, boot it and then try to sideload the image you have. Alternatively search for a custom ROM with a more recent Android version for your device.

Comment: So, for me to do anything, I am not able to unlock the bootloader...it says access denied, even with the unofficial method. Can you suggest me any method?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from ADB sideloading, there is a direct option on the phone called "Apply update from SD card" after entering fastboot mode. Maybe, you should try that.

- Enter fastboot mode by pressing the Volume down and Power button at the same time.
- Once you reach the main menu, look for the above specific option.
- On the SD card, the correct firmware zip file required for your phone should be present. Do NOT rename it or alter it.
- After entering the option, locate the firmware file on the SD card and select it, apply the changes.

If the problem still persists, I think you should dig deeper into how to unlock the bootloader of your phone.